# If one can read a file, can't they also execute it in practice by copying the content and pasting into a new file?

Tags: linux, permissions

I understand what the difference between *read* and *execute* permissions in linux. However, isn't, in practice, having a read permission effectively having execute permission?
After all, if I can read the content of a file, I can copy the content into a new file that I created and execute that file.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the purpose of the execute permission?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385838/whats-the-purpose-of-the-execute-permission) --> "Having it as a permission rather than an attribute of the file is a bit of a historical accident"

Comment: If you can read, you can make a copy to execute. But if you can only execute, you can't read what you're executing.